# How can I create a custom input channel for rasa core?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to create a UI, from where the user can pass voice based messages to Rasa Core. The UI would be hosted on the local server.

Can I create a custom input channel for the same and pass it to the Rasa Core?

Answer (score 0):

yes! you can write a custom input and output channel, here is an example: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/rasa_core/channels/custom.py

however, you will have to use a separate service like the google speech API to first convert the audio to text.